# JSF - Control h:outputLink encoding ISO8859_1/UTF-8?

Tags: jsf

I have a small web application dealing with Jitsi JWT (token-based authentication).
I have a form, asking the user for a Jitsi roomName and so I will create a JWT.
So I generate a URL like `https://<my domain>/<roomName>?jwt=<a token>`

The roomName may contain special chars (blank, german umlaute etc). In Java I build the url from above and print the result in logging (tomcat/primefaces). It looks fine.

Example: `roomName = "abcdefäöüßende"`

The browser is showing the URL to click and launch the Jitsi meeting.
But in the URL the "roomName" is encoded in ISO8859_1 from `<h:outputLink>`

`https://<my domain>/abcdef%E4%F6%FC%DFende?jwt=<a token>`

But Jitsi need the URL encoded with UTF-8 like:

`https://<my domain>/abcdef%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%9Fende?jwt=<a token>`

Is there any possibility to control the h:outputLink behavior?

I have no special ISO8859_1 settings in my project, for me it looks all is UTF-8

Uwe

Comment: You can control page encoding (and consequently the encoding of the `h:outputLink` in a number of ways like in the `web.xml` or on-page in the definition of the XHTML page. Please provide a [mcve] of something that reproduces the issue and we should be able to help you.

Comment: I see this answer to a similar problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24738010/10522925. If you replace the h:outputLink with : <a href="#{bean.germanUrl}"> #{bean.germanUrl}</a>, you are going to fix the issue. Let me know if it works. Regards, Riccardo.

Comment: Hello Riccardo. I found the same solution too. Thanks.
But I didn't found why h:outputLink is converting (yet).
My small web-app is just a prototype yet, later I will do more investigation.Thanks